Error while launching Eclipse platform workspace
Try deleting following file from your workspace and re-launch Eclipse:
YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata
OR,
If this did not help, try launching eclipse from Console as:
C:\PATH_TO_ECLIPSE\eclipse -clean
PS in Mac you will see eclipse.app directory in PATH_TO_ECLIPSE, CD to eclipse.app\contents\MacOs, here you will see eclipse executable.
run this with -clean as:
.\eclipse -clean
i tried it in MY IDE and please help me to resolve this error

Pardon me, but it's not clear (to me, at least) what error you are getting.

Please explain what happens (including any errors you are facing as requested by @Abra), when it happens and what you are trying to do.

Never ever delete the .metadata folder! That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that can cause data loss or wreck your workspace. You can start Eclipse with the option -clean and/or a fresh workspace (-data <empty_workspace_dir>) instead. Please tell what system do you have (x86 or apple silicon; which macOS version?) and what you have downloaded and how you installed it (Eclipse installer or dmg image?).
